# how to write code for Json Array Inside Json Array as Category and subcategory with android

Tags: android, arrays, json, hashmap, expandablelistview

My requirement is simple. i have a json pattern like below. i want to help in JSON parsing. as category and subcategory following way.

```
category-  DIY
subcategory-  Accessories
subcategory-  Garden 
etc..
full pattern will be like 
   DIY
      Accessories
      Garden
      Tools
   Gifts
      Decorative
      Fathers day
      Valentines Day
```

```
{
"CategoryList": [{
    "MainCategory": {
        "Attribute_Name": "DIY",
        "Attribute_Value": "125",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    },
    "SubCategory": [{
        "Attribute_Name": "126",
        "Attribute_Value": "Accessories",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    }, {
        "Attribute_Name": "127",
        "Attribute_Value": "Garden",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    }, {
        "Attribute_Name": "128",
        "Attribute_Value": "Tools",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    }]
}, {
    "MainCategory": {
        "Attribute_Name": "Gifts",
        "Attribute_Value": "133",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    },
    "SubCategory": [{
        "Attribute_Name": "134",
        "Attribute_Value": "Decorative",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    }, {
        "Attribute_Name": "135",
        "Attribute_Value": "Fathers day",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    }, {
        "Attribute_Name": "138",
        "Attribute_Value": "Valentines Day",
        "StockKeepingunit": null
    }]

}],
"status": {
    "message": "Success",
    "result": 1
}}
```

please can any body help me to find the right way to code?

Comment: If you want to learn JSON parsing into android then follow this tutorial...http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
// Here is your sample JSON
String sampleJson = "{\n" +
            "\"CategoryList\": [{\n" +
            "    \"MainCategory\": {\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"DIY\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"125\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"SubCategory\": [{\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"126\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"Accessories\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    }, {\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"127\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"Garden\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    }, {\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"128\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"Tools\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    }]\n" +
            "}, {\n" +
            "    \"MainCategory\": {\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"Gifts\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"133\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"SubCategory\": [{\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"134\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"Decorative\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    }, {\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"135\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"Fathers day\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    }, {\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Name\": \"138\",\n" +
            "        \"Attribute_Value\": \"Valentines Day\",\n" +
            "        \"StockKeepingunit\": null\n" +
            "    }]\n" +
            "\n" +
            "}],\n" +
            "\"status\": {\n" +
            "    \"message\": \"Success\",\n" +
            "    \"result\": 1\n" +
            "}}";
```

Use method `parseJSON(sampleJson)` to parse `Category` and `SubCategory` values from the above `sampleJson` data.

```
public void parseJSON(String jsonStr)
{
    if (jsonStr != null) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // CategoryList
            JSONArray categoryListJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("CategoryList");

            for(int i = 0; i < categoryListJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                // Category
                JSONObject categoryJsonObject = categoryListJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // MainCategory
                JSONObject mainCategoryJsonObject = categoryJsonObject.getJSONObject("MainCategory");

                // Attribute Name
                String attributeName = mainCategoryJsonObject.getString("Attribute_Name");
                Log.d("SUCCESS", "Category: " + attributeName);

                // SubCategory List
                JSONArray subCategoryListJsonArray = categoryJsonObject.getJSONArray("SubCategory");

                for (int j = 0; j < subCategoryListJsonArray.length(); j++)
                {
                    // SubCategory
                    JSONObject subCategoryJsonObject = subCategoryListJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    // Attribute Value
                    String attributeValue = subCategoryJsonObject.getString("Attribute_Value");
                    Log.d("SUCCESS", "Subcategory: " + attributeValue);
                }
            }

        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/SUCCESS: Category: DIY
D/SUCCESS: Subcategory: Accessories
D/SUCCESS: Subcategory: Garden
D/SUCCESS: Subcategory: Tools
D/SUCCESS: Category: Gifts
D/SUCCESS: Subcategory: Decorative
D/SUCCESS: Subcategory: Fathers day
D/SUCCESS: Subcategory: Valentines Day
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you @ Ferdous

Comment: Most welcome :) .... If my answer helps you and seems useful then you should accept this answer and give an upvote. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Happy to know that and thanks for accepting my answer. Please give an upvote if it seems useful to you. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("CategoryList");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("MainCategory");
                    String Attribute_Name = jsonObject2.getString("Attribute_Name");
                    String Attribute_Value = jsonObject2.getString("Attribute_Value");
                    String StockKeepingunit = jsonObject2.getString("StockKeepingunit");

                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("SubCategory");

                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                        String Attribute_Name1 = jsonObject2.getString("Attribute_Name");
                        String Attribute_Value1 = jsonObject2.getString("Attribute_Value");
                        String StockKeepingunit1 = jsonObject2.getString("StockKeepingunit");

                    }
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("status");
                String message = jsonObject1.getString("message");
                int result = jsonObject1.getInt("result");
```

Comment: this is work but it's getting a data into DESC order and set in recyclerview but i want to set data 1st Main Category and after that add a child category but how?? @KuldeepKulkarni