# How to get category and Subcategory data from Json Using Volley

Tags: java, android, json

I Follow below link

- [how to write code for Json Array Inside Json Array as Category and subcategory with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511758/how-to-write-code-for-json-array-inside-json-array-as-category-and-subcategory-w?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But it's cant help for me.

in this link i'll use @Kuldip Kulkerni answer and i'll get data but it's come in to DESC order.

How to i Arrange Main Category and Subcategory and Show in my Recyclerview

What i tried see below codes:

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {

                    JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Pojo dataPojo = new Pojo();
                        dataPojo.id = json_data.getString("category_id");
                        dataPojo.fname = json_data.getString("category_name");
                        dataPojo.thumbnailUrl = json_data.getString("category_image");
                        dataList.add(i, dataPojo);

                        JSONArray jArray1 = json_data.getJSONArray("subcategory");

                        for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject json_data1 = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                            Pojo dataPojo1 = new Pojo();
                            dataPojo1.id2 = json_data1.getString("category_id");
                            dataPojo1.fname2 = json_data1.getString("category_name");
                            dataList.add(j, dataPojo1);
                        }

                    }

                    dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(dataList);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
```

- Above code is a getting a data of Main category but can't getting subcategory data

Below is my `Pojo.java` class :

```
public class Pojo {

    public String id;
    public String fname;
    public String thumbnailUrl;
    public String id2;
    public String fname2;

    public Pojo() {
    }

    public Pojo(String id, String fname, String thumbnailUrl, String id2, String fname2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        this.id2 = id2;
        this.fname2 = fname2;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public String getId2() {
        return id2;
    }

    public void setId2(String id2) {
        this.id2 = id2;
    }

    public String getFname2() {
        return fname2;
    }

    public void setFname2(String fname2) {
        this.fname2 = fname2;
    }

}
```

**`Json`** Response:

[image]

so how to i solve this can anyone help

**EIDT QUESTION AFTER FOLLOWING @Birju ANSWER**

[image]

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: how about using retrofit and moshi/gson to simplify things? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changes for your Pojo class

```
public class Pojo {

private String catagory_id;
private String catagory_name;
private String catagory_thumbnailUrl;
private ArrayList<SubCatagory> subCatagoryArrayList;

public ArrayList<SubCatagory> getSubCatagoryArrayList() {
    return subCatagoryArrayList;
}

public void setSubCatagoryArrayList(ArrayList<SubCatagory> subCatagoryArrayList) {
    this.subCatagoryArrayList = subCatagoryArrayList;
}

public String getCatagory_id() {
    return catagory_id;
}

public void setCatagory_id(String catagory_id) {
    this.catagory_id = catagory_id;
}

public String getCatagory_name() {
    return catagory_name;
}

public void setCatagory_name(String catagory_name) {
    this.catagory_name = catagory_name;
}

public String getCatagory_thumbnailUrl() {
    return catagory_thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setCatagory_thumbnailUrl(String catagory_thumbnailUrl) {
    this.catagory_thumbnailUrl = catagory_thumbnailUrl;
}
}
```

add new class as SubCatagory

```
public class SubCatagory {
private String subcatagory_id;
private String subcatagory_name;


public String getSubcatagory_id() {
    return subcatagory_id;
}

public void setSubcatagory_id(String subcatagory_id) {
    this.subcatagory_id = subcatagory_id;
}

public String getSubcatagory_name() {
    return subcatagory_name;
}

public void setSubcatagory_name(String subcatagory_name) {
    this.subcatagory_name = subcatagory_name;
}
}
```

and in your onResponce()

```
  try {

                JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Pojo dataPojo = new Pojo(); //this is catagory class
                    dataPojo.setCatagory_id(json_data.getString("category_id"));
                    dataPojo.setCatagory_name(json_data.getString("category_name"));
                    dataPojo.setCatagory_thumbnailUrl(json_data.getString("category_image"));


                    JSONArray jArray1 = json_data.getJSONArray("subcategory");

                    ArrayList<SubCatagory> subCatagoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject json_data1 = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                        SubCatagory subCatagory = new SubCatagory(); // this is subcatagory class
                        subCatagory.setSubcatagory_id(json_data1.getString("category_id"));
                        subCatagory.setSubcatagory_name(json_data1.getString("category_name"));
                        subCatagoryArrayList.add(subCatagory);
                    }
                    dataPojo.setSubCatagoryArrayList(subCatagoryArrayList);//this i insert subcatagory in catagory 
                    dataList.add(dataPojo); // and after i add catagory to datalist 
                }

              /*  dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(dataList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
  }
```

**NOTE: - 1** comment `recyclerview` and `dataadapter` and check `responce` vales in debug mode because i use `getter` `setter` for variable (for follow coding structure :dont make variable public...

- 2 don't replace my code directly...first comment your old code

and inside your

> dataadapter -> in method onbindviewholder(){
>
> Pojo catagory=dataList.get(position); // this give you catagory
>
> Arraylist subcatagory =
>   catagory.getSubCatagoryArrayList();///this is subcatagory
>   arraylist...using for loop you can get subcatagory data
>
> }